# How to monitor a particular queue of RabbitMQ using rabbitmq_prometheus plugin?

Tags: rabbitmq, prometheus, monitoring, grafana

Is there a way to monitor a particular queue on RabbitMQ using "rabbitmq_prometheus" plugin? I am looking something like if a particular queue has 0 consumers, Prometheus should monitor it.

"rabbitmq_queue_consumers" metric gives sum of consumers for all queues for that instance but I am looking for a particular queue, something like

> rabbitmq_queue_consumers{queue=service-queue-A}

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to return per-object (unaggregated) metrics on the /metrics endpoint, set prometheus.return_per_object_metrics to true:
`prometheus.return_per_object_metrics = true` in the rabbitmq config file.

RabbitMQ offers a dedicated endpoint, `/metrics/per-object`, which always returns per-object metrics, regardless of the value of prometheus.return_per_object_metrics

more information.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html